# Python - Calculating in dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, calculation

I am having problems with calculating in dataframes.

I am calculating the

- %-change per column
- %-share per column based on the sum of the row

Now I want to calculate the %-change per column based on the %-share per column. I would do that like the following:

(col A %-change * col A %-share) + (col B %-change * col B %-share) + (col C %-change * col C %-share) and so on.

I thought of two ways to do that, though neither is working… And – of course – I would like to do it as dynamically as possible as the number of columns will vary.

Here is some code to get a fitting dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['2019-04-29', 5, 5, 10],
    ['2019-04-28', 10, 10, 50],
    ['2019-04-27', 20, 5, 100]]),
    columns=['Date', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'])

    df1["attr1"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["attr1"])
    df1["attr2"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["attr2"])
    df1["attr3"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["attr3"])

    df1 = df1.set_index(['Date'])
    col_list= list(df1)

    df1['sum'] = df1[col_list].sum(axis=1)

    for i in col_list:
    df1[i + ' %-change'] = df1[i].pct_change()*100
    df1[i + " %-share"] = df1[i]/ df1['sum']
```

Idea 1: 
Basically I am trying the formula mentioned above. So multiply the %-share and the %-change of each column and sum these up. I thought about using .sum but don´t know how to use it in this specific situation.

```
df1[i + ' %-change incl share'] = (df1[i + ' %-share'] * df1[i + ' %-change'])
```

Idea 2:
Thought about doing this in two steps. Step one would be to multiply the %-share and the %-change of each column. The second step would be to sum up the new columns in a new code line. The problem is I can´t make it dynamically. I would have to manually select the columns I need to summarize, but if I am having let’s say a 100 columns that would be tedious work indeed.

I thought about writing the newly calculated columns into a new dataframe so I´ve got all the columns I need, but the data in the dataframe make no sense to me.

```
df2[i + ' %-change incl share'] = (df1[i + ' %-share'] * df1[i + ' %-change'])
```

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use dataframe.apply with lumbda function.

```py
# get the column name out
changeCol = [col for col in df1.columns if 'change' in col]
shareCol = [col for col in df1.columns if 'share' in col]

# calculate
result = df1.apply(lambda x: sum([x[changeCol[i]]*x[shareCol[i]] for i in range(len(changeCol))]), axis=1)

# after you could append the result to your dataframe or do whatever you like.
# df1["result"] = result
# ...
```

[ref]
[pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)